# Retain ajax populated value in dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have a form where two dropdowns are kept. When the value on first is selected, ajax call is made to show related results as second dropdown list. My issue is when value is selected on second dropdown and form is submitted the second dropdown list(which is being populated on basis of first selection made in first select box) gets empty. I want to retain the value into the second dropdown selected after form submit. Can I have some insight over the same.

```
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <label for="username" class="control-label">Select Level:</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-9">
<select name="levels" class="form-control"  required="" id = "level">
    <?php $fnc->selectBoxsearchLevel("tbl_levels_master","id","level_title", $level_id) ; ?>
</select>  
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#level").change(function() {
    var level_id = $(this).val();
    if(level_id != "") {
      $.ajax({
        url:"get_units.php",
        data:{l_id:level_id},
        type:'POST',
        success:function(response) {
        //console.log (response);
          var resp = $.trim(response);
          $("#unit").html(resp);
        }
      });
    } else {
      $("#unit").html("<option value=''>------- Selected --------</option>");
    }
  });
});
       </script>   
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <label for="username" class="control-label">Select Unit:</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-9">
<select name="units" class="form-control"  required="" id= "unit">

<option>------- Select --------</option>
</select>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

And my `get_units.php`

```
<?php

$db = new Database(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE); 

$level_id = $_POST['l_id'];

    $sql = "select * from tbl where level=$level_id";
    $res = $db->query($sql);


        echo "<option value=''>------- Select --------</option>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
            echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['title']."</option>";

        }
    ?>
```

Comment: So concluding your use case you have two select options assume for now simple as country and state based on selection of country you are populating the states of that respective country. Clicking on the submit the Country select box goes to empty. So even though you submit you need the Selected Country and state to be persistent in the form , is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: Ya @DILEEPTHOMAS . This is the thing.